# Access Debian server folder via web browser with user login

Tags: debian, webserver, file-server

I just signed up with digital ocean for my Debian server.

In the server I created multiple users, each user having an access to 1 different folder to view files in there.

Now what I want to do is to access that folder from my web browser and login with username and password so that I can start view my txt file.

What is the approach that I should take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a web server, for instance Apache, setting up users areas, and WebDAV services if you want users to write files there.

As an introduction to the theme:[how to configure webdav access with apache on ubuntu-14-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-webdav-access-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)

For starters, you can do:

```
sudo apt install apache2
sudo a2enmod dav
sudo a2enmod dav_fs
```

The user authentication will depend on the method you created the users.

Comment: will come back to improve this, on my phone